# Toast não é exibido

Tags: java, android, thread

Estou com um problema o Toast não aparece quando faço um request no para o meu web service, todo o método fica dentro da minha thread, fiz um teste colocando uma mensagem fora da thread ai ele aparece, mas bem onde eu preciso, ele não exibe com a mensagem que preciso mostrar para o usuário.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {

                  try {
                      loginDao = new LoginDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                      login = loginDao.queryForId(1);
                  } catch (SQLException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  DadosCadastraisSerealizable dados = new DadosCadastraisSerealizable();


                  dados.codigo= String.valueOf(login.getCodigoCliente());
                  dados.usuario=login.usuario;
                  dados.senha=login.senha;

                  //expressão regular para enviar somente o numeros.
                  String[] cepText = edtCep.getText().toString().split("-");


                  dados.cep= cepText[0]+cepText[1];
                  dados.bairro= edtBairro.getText().toString();
                  dados.endereco= edtEndereco.getText().toString();
                  dados.numero= edtnumero.getText().toString();
                  dados.complemento= edtComplemento.getText().toString();
                  dados.foneComercial= edtFoneComercial.getText().toString();
                  dados.foneResidencial= edtFoneResidencial.getText().toString();
                  dados.foneCelular= edtFoneCelular.getText().toString();
                  dados.email= edtEmail.getText().toString();



                  try {
                      WebService ws = new WebService();

                      ws.atuzalizarCadastroCliente(dados);

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ws.strFault, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }



              }
          }).start();


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só pode modificar a "tela" dentro da `thread` principal, a `MainThread`.
Faça isso no local que precisa que deve funcionar.

```
SuaAcitivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ws.strFault, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Assim o `Toast` é solicitado dentro da `thread` principal sem problema.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro: O método run não aceita modificações na interface a partir dele..

Segundo: use AsyncTask.